# I am getting an incorrect information from GetExpressCheckoutDetails option

Tags: paypal

Hello I am using NVP API from PayPal. I have been this calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails, but in some customers I am getting different Shiptostreet, shiptostreet2, shiptocity, shiptostate, shiptozip and shiptocountry code. I check in my paypal account about the order and I see the data, and in my system I am getting different data.

regards

Comment: Can you share the response that you're getting from the API?

Comment: Would need to see a sample of the data showing up on the PayPal transaction details page compared with the GECD response from the matching transaction ID.  If that sort of thing is really happening you'll need to [submit it directly to PayPal MTS](https://www.paypal.com/mts) and make sure to provide that example for them clearly.

Answer (score 0):

GetExpressCheckoutDetails return the address information shown to user in the review page during checkout.